# Questions about adding a WCF service to a Windows service assembly

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, windows-services

I have found some basic information about hosting a WCF service in a Windows service, but not much. All of my experience thus far with WCF has been in Web projects. I have a few simple questions.

I have a project which creates a windows service application. I have done a right click -> add WCF Service. This creates Service1.cs and IService1.cs.

1. I'm wondering why no SVC file is created in this scenario? When I add services to Web projects i get an SVC file which I can navigate to and use to consume the service.
2. Adding the service adds some configurations to the app.config under the services element. I'm seeing a default base address of

   http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WindowsServiceName.services/WCFServiceName/

What does this mean? It's sort of an odd looking address. Am I supposed to change it to whatever I want?

1. Navigating to this address in a browser results in an unable to connect message. Does the windows service itself have to be running to talk to the WCF service?
2. How do I go about consuming this service from another application without an svc file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm taking a guess on this first one, but I'm thinking the .svc file when hosting in IIS is to tell IIS, "Hey I have a WCF service here, please handle accordingly".

The base address is as it should be and yes you can change it if I'm not mistaken.

You can't hit the WCF service unless the Windows service is running, which is one of the dangers of hosting in a Windows service, because if the service dies somehow your WCF service is offline until you get the Windows service running again.

You consume the service the same way you do any other WCF service, just using that base address to get at it.

Comment: Thanks. The part that throws me off about the address is 'design_time_addresses'. leads me to believe this is not going to be a valid address at run time.